# Get checkbox's ID

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I need to get the ID of checkboxes in a table in the `<tbody>` section. I have a live(click) function that I want to bring up a popup with the data that i want based in the id in the checkbox.

I want to also allow the system, to have multiple checkboxes checked I want to be able to store the ids in a temp var and the use them as needed and get rid of them as I go though them.

Comment: Why do you need the IDs? Why don't just get a reference to all selected checkboxes (which is easy with jQuery)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just get id with `.attr`:

```
$("#container input:checkbox").attr("id")
```

To get an array of checkboxes ids you might use `.map` function:

```
var idArr = $("#container input:checkbox").map(function(i, el) { return $(el).attr("id"); }).get();
```

Comment: That returns the `id` of the first checkbox.

Comment: So I would take it I would do a .each function before I call one of those?

Comment: @Russell: Yes, as in jfriend00's answer.

Comment: You don't have to use `each` for second line of code (using `map`)

Answer (score 1):

`$("#container input:checkbox")` will be a jQuery object of all the checkboxes inside a particular div with an `id` of `container`.  You can store that value and use it in the future to carry out all sorts of jQuery operations.

If you want to collect all the DOM objects into a separate array, you can just do a `.get()` on it.

```
var domObjects = $("#container input:checkbox").get();
```

If you want to get all the ids into an array, you could do it this way:

```
var idArray = [];
$("#container input:checkbox").each(function() {
    idArray.push(this.id);
});
```

Comment: how do I make sure I only get the checked ID

Comment: `$("#container input:checkbox:checked")` will get you only the checkboxes that are checked.  See here for demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Jqh36/.